# Javascript waiting for click event after an initial button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After I click on a button, I'm waiting for a user click on an element with a specific classname. I'm using await/async as follows:

```
function waitingForNodeClick(){
  return new Promise(resolve=>{
    console.log("in promise")
    document.body.addEventListener('click',(event)=>{
      const classClicked = event.target.className.split(" ")[0]
      console.log(event)
      if (classClicked==="node"){
        resolve()
      }
    },{once: true})
  })
}

async function handleSetStart(){
  console.log("waiting for click on any node")
  await waitingForNodeClick()
  console.log("clicked")
}

<button onClick={handleSetStart}>SELECT START NODE</button>
```

output from the above:

```
waiting for click on any node
in promise
click { target: button, buttons: 0, clientX: 916, clientY: 8, layerX: 916, layerY: 8 }
```

The problem with this is that it seems to take the click on the initial button as the event in the `waitingForNodeClick` function, and so the second click on the "node" element is ignored. Is there anyway I can ignore the initial button click in the handler?

Comment: _"it seems to take the click on the initial button as the event in the waitingForNodeClick function"_ - well that _is_ the `e` that was passed into your `handleSetStart` function, and which you are using in this call of `waitingForNodeClick`, so what else did you expect?

Comment: apologies, I removed the redundant code. The event being passed into `handleSetStart` is never used anyway. I'm concerned about `event` in the `document.body.addEventListener` callback function. When I log the event from the eventlistener, it turns out to be the initial button click @CBroe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try canceling the event handling:

```
async function handleSetStart(e){
  e.stopPropagation()

  console.log("waiting for click on any node")
  await waitingForNodeClick()
  console.log("clicked")
}
```